# How to export objects from wikimapia to openstreetmap?

Tags: openstreetmap, export, wikimapia

How to export objects (buildings, houses) from wikimapia to openstreetmap? What is the way?

Answer (score 5):

First you have to be sure such data importing into OSM would be legal. Judging from this thread, I would say no: http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=7076

> Wikimapia is essentially derived from Google aerial imagery, so steer
>   clear. Furthermore the license terms stipulate non-commercial use.

Comment: Thank you. I want to try add a few objects to OSM from Wikimapia and send it to server and just wait for accepting or not. So what is the way to export from Wikimapia to OSM?

Comment: And I don't need to use aerial imagery from Wikimapia.

Comment: There is no "accepting" as such, there are no data import moderators in OSM. Whatever you add to OSM will automatically be a part of its database. Regardless of whether you used aerial imagery or not, the license of Wikimapia applies to all of its data the same. If the license is not compatible with OSM's, then such an import into OSM is not legal. So before asking the technical side of things, make sure this is allowed.

Comment: You can use Bing Maps Aerial for OSM - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bing#Announcement_and_licence

Answer (score 0):

Do not. Licenses are incompatible.